# How to open 8080 port to access tomcat home page from Redhat instance?

Tags: java, linux, tomcat, rhel

I have tomcat 7.0.52 in redhat instance and started the server.So i want to access the tomcat home page through http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8080 in my local system, but i'm not getting any response.

But when i was accessing same for system for telnet its working good.So i made some changes in iptables and selinux files.

```
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT
```

and

```
SELINUX=disabled
SELINUXTYPE=targeted
```

from /etc/sysconfig/selinux.

I try test the port is listening using netstat -tulnp | grep 8080

```
tcp        0      0 :::8080        :::*                        LISTEN      2406/java
```

Eventhough i am not able to access the tomcat home page.

Comment: If you are trying to access on local machine, didnt `http://127.0.0.1:8080/` too work?

Comment: My local system is windows and linux where i have tomcat. So i try to access tomcat home page from windows , its not connecting.

Comment: When you updated the iptables file did you actually restart iptables?  Did you reboot the system?

Comment: restarted iptables with `/etc/init.d/iptables restart`` and reboot.